# building release apk for android in react native fails for svg files

Tags: android, react-native, svg

I am getting the below error while trying to build a react native android release build. All my images are in svg format.

```
:app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> /Users/shamnad.shaji/Workspace/React-Native/project/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/images_defaultprofile.svg: Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.514 secs
```

I google this error and people have suggested to include the `android.disableResourceValidation=true` option in my gradle.properties file.

My `gradle.properties` looks like this.

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=password
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=password
android.disableResourceValidation=true
```

And my steps to run release build are.

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bu‌​ndle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
cd android/
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Could someone suggest me what to do?.

Comment: When we include a svg in android studio it automatically becomes .xml You might want to rename it

Comment: Then I would have to rename each file right? . `<Image source={require('../../images/default-profile.svg')} />` . This is how I use them common to android and ios.

Comment: convert those to .png it will remove those errors  https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/109

Comment: Yes thats the only way. I did it and now it works fine.

Comment: @ShamnadPS, i'm getting same issue on release only, did u manage to fix it ?

Comment: Please change svg to png. Thats the quick solution.

Comment: Is there no solution using svg? I got the same problem on release build only.

Answer (score 0):

I think svg support is not introduced yet https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/109

you can convert your images to .png. It doesn't required any libraries to render those.

But if you want .svg. you can use below library to render your svg images

https://github.com/vault-development/react-native-svg-uri

**don't use this svg library as well convert it to .png. This library also failed while release in android I just saw**

Comment: Then I would have to rename each file right? . `<Image source={require('../../images/default-profile.svg')} />` . This is how I use them common to android and ios.

Comment: This is not the issue. Please read my question. I only have problems with release build. simulator works fine.

Comment: are u using https://github.com/vault-development/react-native-svg-uri ?

Answer (score -1):

i recommend using **react-native-svg** for including svg files in react native!